# Why is systemd-resolved restarting frequently?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, amazon-ec2

After upgrading an EC2 instance to Ubuntu 18.04 I started getting occasional errors Resolving DNS for my database server in my PHP scripts like the following:

```
Uncaught Exception: PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

These correlate in syslog with a restart of systemd-resolved. I turned on debug logging, but I still don't see why the service is getting restarted several times a day. Here are the syslog entries surrounding a restart:

```
Dec 6 11:31:20 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Processing incoming packet on transaction 51967. (rcode=SUCCESS)
Dec 6 11:31:20 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Processing query...
Dec 6 11:31:20 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Cache miss for sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com IN A, Cache miss for sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com IN A @version:1 @timestamp:December 6th 2018, 05:31:20.000
Dec 6 11:31:20 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Removing cache entry for gmail-imap.l.google.com IN AAAA (expired 19s ago)
Dec 6 11:31:22 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Removing scope on link *, protocol dns, family *
Dec 6 11:31:22 ip-172-31-X-X dhclient[768]: DHCPREQUEST of 172.31.X.X on eth0 to 172.31.32.X port 67 (xid=0x66c614b9)
Dec 6 11:31:22 ip-172-31-X-X dhclient[768]: DHCPACK of 172.31.X.X from 172.31.32.X
Dec 6 11:31:22 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15188]: Bus n/a: changing state RUNNING → CLOSED
Dec 6 11:31:22 ip-172-31-X-X systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Dec 6 11:31:23 ip-172-31-X-X dhclient[768]: bound to 172.31.X.X -- renewal in 1565 seconds.
Dec 6 11:31:23 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15465]: Got message type=signal sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.2496 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=NameAcquired cookie=3 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Dec 6 11:31:23 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15465]: Found new link 2/eth0
Dec 6 11:31:23 ip-172-31-X-X systemd-resolved[15465]: New scope on link *, protocol dns, family *
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf` seems to be the default AWS one and is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` which contains:

```
nameserver 172.31.0.X
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

Anyone know why I'm getting these seemingly random restarts and what I can do to fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me the root cause it was `systemd-resolved` restarting on `dhclient` and from your logs I bet for you as well

have a look at this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1805183

after applying the working patch https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1805183/comments/8 php-fpm (and getaddrinfo) never complained anymore.

Comment: That looks very promising, thank you. I'll let you know if that works.

Comment: @MichaelOConnell did it solve your issue? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this problem, and you do not want to apply the linked patch, there is an alternative solution for the temporary DNS errors.

Disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu.  There is an explanation [here, on our sister site for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu).

I will not copy the explanation here.  There is already one caveat about disabling systemd-resolved.  If I copy the explanation into this answer, then this answer could miss other important updates.

Comment: I am fairly certain this is a valid solution as well